# How to remove splash activity from an existing project?

Tags: java, android

I have an existing Android Studio project and i wanted to remove splash screen. I tried to remove changes in AndroidManifest.xml but couldn't make it.

Here this my actual AndroidManifest.xml

```
      <!-- Home Tab Group -->
    <activity
        android:name=".view.TabHomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".view.activity.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".view.activity.TestLoginFacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        >
    </activity>

   <!-- Tab Screen -->

    <activity android:name=".view.tabscreen.TabHomeScreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Delete the SplashActivity class,
- delete it's layout,
- delete it from the manifest.
- Add the intent filters to your TabHomeActivity.

  ```
  <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Delete the `SplashActivity` class,delete it from the `manifest`. Set the `Launching` Activity first which you want to come as your first screen

```
 <activity
            android:name=".view.TabHomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden" >
     <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<activity
    android:name=".view.activity.TestLoginFacebookActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
    >
</activity>
```